# Creating a raster dataset but plot error

Tags: r, r-raster, rgdal

l m learning `R tool` and l followed an example but although l did everything same ,l got an error during `the plot raster`.

here is the code:

```
library(raster)
library(rgdal)

myRaster1 <- raster(nrow=4, ncol=4)
myRaster1[]<- 1:ncell(myRaster1)
myRaster2=raster(nrow=8, ncol=8)
resample(myRaster1, myRaster2, method='bilinear')
plot(myRaster2, main="Raster with 32 pixels")
```

here is the error warnings:

```
Error in .plotraster2(x, col = col, maxpixels = maxpixels, add = add,  : 
  no values associated with this RasterLayer
```

how can l solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to give a name to your resampled Raster:

```
library(raster)
library(rgdal)

myRaster1 <- raster(nrow=4, ncol=4)
myRaster1[]<- 1:ncell(myRaster1)
myRaster2=raster(nrow=8, ncol=8)
myRaster1.resampled <- resample(myRaster1, myRaster2, method='bilinear')
plot(myRaster1.resampled, main="Raster with 32 pixels")
```

Comment: l do not get why l need to give a name as on example ,without giving a name ,it runs. after resampling the raster ,it does not convert in new raster as far as l understand, right?

Comment: A new raster is created with `resample` but you did not stored it. Thus the function does not give an error message because it does the job. But then you can not use the created raster because you do not know where it is...